# I cannot change my ubuntu user account password

Tags: 11.10, password, users

Changing the user account password seems to take forever. Do any of you have this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple command:

```
sudo passwd $USER
```

where `$USER` is name of user account or just

```
passwd
```

to change the password of the account you are running command from, then type ur current password and then new password and then retype it. :)

Comment: `sudo passwd` is **not** the same as `password`! `passwd` changes the password for the user running the command, with `sudo` this becomes root. Use `sudo passwd $USER` to change the password for user `$USER`